# gitlab-ci.yml sonar integration for angular. lcov.info not found. Problems with code coverage

Tags: angular, typescript, sonarqube, code-coverage, gitlab-ci

I am currently trying to integrate sonar in our angular project. It works locally but i cant get it to run properly on gitlab-ci, i dont get coverage there.

Here is my gitlab-ci.yml entry

```
clientsonar:
  image: node:10.16.3
  allow_failure: true
  artifacts:
    expire_in: 1 days
    when: always
    paths:
      - "*/coverage"
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - apt-get update
    - apt-get install --fix-missing
    - apt-get install default-jre -y
  script:
    - cd ./frontend-web
    - yarn install
    - yarn sonar
```

the yarn sonar command (sonar-scanner version 3.1.0)

```
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner",
```

Here is my sonar.project.properties

```
sonar.host.url=*URL*
sonar.login=*LOGIN*
sonar.projectKey=*KEY*
sonar.projectName=*NAME*
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8
sonar.sources=src
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/*.spec.ts
sonar.tests=src
sonar.test.inclusions=**/*.spec.ts
sonar.typescript.lcov.reportPaths=coverage/lcov.info
```

In the gitlab pipeline i get the following log message

```
 WARN: No coverage information will be saved because LCOV file cannot be found.
 WARN: Provided LCOV file path: coverage/lcov.info. Seek file with path: /builds/path/to/frontend-web/coverage/lcov.info
 WARN: No coverage information will be saved because all LCOV coverage report files cannot be found.
```

I tried adding an empty lcov.info to git. According to the created artifact this file remains empty.

Static code analysis works, but i dont get my coverage.

I am kinda stuck right now. Thanks in advance.